# Q: Disable "zoom in/out" on scroll at scene

Tags: roomle

We use the base repo "Roomle UI" based on the "Roomle Web SDK". We are currently customizing this and integrating it into our website accordingly. We would like to deactivate the automatic "zoom in" via scrolling. It interrupts the intended user flow. Unfortunately we haven't found a way to implement this yet without keeping the classic functionality like drag n drop.
Do you guys have any suggestions to handle this?

Answer (score 3):

Currently that's not possible. Please create a feature request here: https://roomle.atlassian.net/servicedesk/customer/portal/4/group/5/create/24

What you could try (**but be aware that this relies on private apis and those apis can break at any time in the future**) is the following:

### !!Warning the next snippet changes private apis!!

```
window.deactivated = true;
var oldOnMouseWheel = RoomleConfigurator._sceneManager._cameraControl._inputManager._onMouseWheel.bind(RoomleConfigurator._sceneHelper._cameraControl._inputManager);

RoomleConfigurator._sceneManager._cameraControl._inputManager._onMouseWheel = function () {
  console.log('!!!!WARNING WE CHANGED A PRIVATE METHOD!!!!');
  if (window.deactivated) {
    return;
  }
  oldOnMouseWheel(...arguments);
};
```

And then to active/deactive you just would need to set `window.deactivated` to `true` or `false`.

### **But as a reminder, those are private apis which will break  eventually**