# after update: Disable "zoom in/out" on scroll at scene needs new idea

Tags: roomle

first off, I know the warning was there, so everything is fine
but the solution to following is not working anymore after updating to 2.32.0:
[Q: Disable "zoom in/out" on scroll at scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69906551/q-disable-zoom-in-out-on-scroll-at-scene)

any other idea how we can avoid zooming with scrolling again in the new version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Q: Disable "zoom in/out" on scroll at scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69906551/q-disable-zoom-in-out-on-scroll-at-scene)

Comment: I updated the code in the original answer